# Prepend the last lines of a file to the beginning of a file

Tags: python, file

I have several hundred data files with following structure:

```
ATOM      1  CG  TYR C  58     121.612 160.894 112.763  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      2  CD1 TYR C  58     120.943 162.067 113.040  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      3  CD2 TYR C  58     121.188 159.746 113.389  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      4  CE1 TYR C  58     119.873 162.092 113.912  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      5  CE2 TYR C  58     120.129 159.760 114.258  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      6  CZ  TYR C  58     119.475 160.934 114.519  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      7  OH  TYR C  58     118.415 160.939 115.392  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM      8  OD1 ASN C  60     119.864 156.037 117.108  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM      9  CG  PHE C  77     122.548 156.511 110.481  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     10  CD1 PHE C  77     122.075 155.486 109.711  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     11  CD2 PHE C  77     122.223 156.541 111.807  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     12  CE1 PHE C  77     121.216 154.566 110.224  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     13  CE2 PHE C  77     121.377 155.605 112.335  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     14  CZ  PHE C  77     120.877 154.618 111.540  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     15  NZ  LYS D 156     112.602 154.253 117.823  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     16  O   ILE D 202     108.373 159.140 111.337  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     17  N   VAL D 203     109.786 157.858 110.154  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     18  CA  VAL D 203     110.994 158.530 110.614  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     19  C   VAL D 203     111.459 159.524 109.568  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     20  CB  VAL D 203     112.099 157.518 110.929  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     21  CG1 VAL D 203     113.424 158.213 111.097  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     22  CG2 VAL D 203     111.757 156.818 112.216  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     23  N   GLN D 204     111.583 160.788 109.970  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     24  O   GLN D 204     114.017 162.417 110.404  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     25  CA  SER D 205     115.779 162.096 108.277  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     26  CB  SER D 205     116.596 160.967 107.666  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     27  OG  SER D 205     117.961 161.337 107.661  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     28  C   UNL X   1     111.662 159.873 113.972  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     29  N   UNL X   1     113.085 160.155 114.126  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     30  C   UNL X   1     113.499 161.458 113.812  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     31  O   UNL X   1     112.732 162.299 113.334  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     32  C   UNL X   1     114.928 161.844 114.171  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     33  N   UNL X   1     115.842 161.124 113.296  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     34  C   UNL X   1     116.000 159.854 113.475  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     35  C   UNL X   1     115.326 159.120 114.591  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     36  C   UNL X   1     116.110 158.332 115.447  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     37  C   UNL X   1     115.508 157.476 116.361  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     38  CL  UNL X   1     116.480 156.444 117.332  1.00  0.00          CL
ATOM     39  C   UNL X   1     114.125 157.429 116.470  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     40  C   UNL X   1     113.345 158.291 115.696  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     41  C   UNL X   1     113.925 159.189 114.776  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     42  C   UNL X   1     116.862 159.133 112.452  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     43  C   UNL X   1     116.961 157.743 112.314  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     44  C   UNL X   1     117.837 157.173 111.379  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     45  C   UNL X   1     118.592 157.982 110.536  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     46  C   UNL X   1     118.471 159.363 110.623  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     47  C   UNL X   1     117.619 159.931 111.575  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     48  H   UNL X   1     111.189 160.691 113.471  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     49  H   UNL X   1     111.218 159.741 114.937  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     50  H   UNL X   1     111.536 158.980 113.396  1.00  0.00           H
END
```

My goal is to take the lines that have `UNL X`  in them and reinsert them to the beginning of the file, and delete their initial position.

However, what I end up with is my code writing in the lines starting at `ATOM     50` then counting down to `ATOM     49` then `ATOM     48` etc., etc. Essentially, my code prepends to the file backwards and doesn't delete the `UNL X`  lines at beginning of the file, making the final result look like:

```
ATOM     50  H   UNL X   1     111.536 158.980 113.396  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     49  H   UNL X   1     111.218 159.741 114.937  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     48  H   UNL X   1     111.189 160.691 113.471  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     47  C   UNL X   1     117.619 159.931 111.575  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     46  C   UNL X   1     118.471 159.363 110.623  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     45  C   UNL X   1     118.592 157.982 110.536  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     44  C   UNL X   1     117.837 157.173 111.379  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     43  C   UNL X   1     116.961 157.743 112.314  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     42  C   UNL X   1     116.862 159.133 112.452  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     41  C   UNL X   1     113.925 159.189 114.776  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     40  C   UNL X   1     113.345 158.291 115.696  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     39  C   UNL X   1     114.125 157.429 116.470  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     38  CL  UNL X   1     116.480 156.444 117.332  1.00  0.00          CL
ATOM     37  C   UNL X   1     115.508 157.476 116.361  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     36  C   UNL X   1     116.110 158.332 115.447  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     35  C   UNL X   1     115.326 159.120 114.591  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     34  C   UNL X   1     116.000 159.854 113.475  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     33  N   UNL X   1     115.842 161.124 113.296  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     32  C   UNL X   1     114.928 161.844 114.171  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     31  O   UNL X   1     112.732 162.299 113.334  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     30  C   UNL X   1     113.499 161.458 113.812  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     29  N   UNL X   1     113.085 160.155 114.126  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     28  C   UNL X   1     111.662 159.873 113.972  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      1  CG  TYR C  58     121.612 160.894 112.763  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      2  CD1 TYR C  58     120.943 162.067 113.040  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      3  CD2 TYR C  58     121.188 159.746 113.389  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      4  CE1 TYR C  58     119.873 162.092 113.912  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      5  CE2 TYR C  58     120.129 159.760 114.258  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      6  CZ  TYR C  58     119.475 160.934 114.519  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      7  OH  TYR C  58     118.415 160.939 115.392  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM      8  OD1 ASN C  60     119.864 156.037 117.108  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM      9  CG  PHE C  77     122.548 156.511 110.481  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     10  CD1 PHE C  77     122.075 155.486 109.711  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     11  CD2 PHE C  77     122.223 156.541 111.807  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     12  CE1 PHE C  77     121.216 154.566 110.224  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     13  CE2 PHE C  77     121.377 155.605 112.335  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     14  CZ  PHE C  77     120.877 154.618 111.540  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     15  NZ  LYS D 156     112.602 154.253 117.823  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     16  O   ILE D 202     108.373 159.140 111.337  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     17  N   VAL D 203     109.786 157.858 110.154  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     18  CA  VAL D 203     110.994 158.530 110.614  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     19  C   VAL D 203     111.459 159.524 109.568  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     20  CB  VAL D 203     112.099 157.518 110.929  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     21  CG1 VAL D 203     113.424 158.213 111.097  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     22  CG2 VAL D 203     111.757 156.818 112.216  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     23  N   GLN D 204     111.583 160.788 109.970  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     24  O   GLN D 204     114.017 162.417 110.404  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     25  CA  SER D 205     115.779 162.096 108.277  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     26  CB  SER D 205     116.596 160.967 107.666  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     27  OG  SER D 205     117.961 161.337 107.661  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     28  C   UNL X   1     111.662 159.873 113.972  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     29  N   UNL X   1     113.085 160.155 114.126  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     30  C   UNL X   1     113.499 161.458 113.812  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     31  O   UNL X   1     112.732 162.299 113.334  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     32  C   UNL X   1     114.928 161.844 114.171  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     33  N   UNL X   1     115.842 161.124 113.296  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM     34  C   UNL X   1     116.000 159.854 113.475  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     35  C   UNL X   1     115.326 159.120 114.591  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     36  C   UNL X   1     116.110 158.332 115.447  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     37  C   UNL X   1     115.508 157.476 116.361  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     38  CL  UNL X   1     116.480 156.444 117.332  1.00  0.00          CL
ATOM     39  C   UNL X   1     114.125 157.429 116.470  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     40  C   UNL X   1     113.345 158.291 115.696  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     41  C   UNL X   1     113.925 159.189 114.776  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     42  C   UNL X   1     116.862 159.133 112.452  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     43  C   UNL X   1     116.961 157.743 112.314  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     44  C   UNL X   1     117.837 157.173 111.379  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     45  C   UNL X   1     118.592 157.982 110.536  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     46  C   UNL X   1     118.471 159.363 110.623  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     47  C   UNL X   1     117.619 159.931 111.575  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     48  H   UNL X   1     111.189 160.691 113.471  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     49  H   UNL X   1     111.218 159.741 114.937  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     50  H   UNL X   1     111.536 158.980 113.396  1.00  0.00           H
END
```

Heres what I've tried so far:

```
import os



def prepend_line(file_name, line):
    with open(file_name, "r+") as f: s = f.read(); f.seek(0); f.write(line + s)

pathway = r'C:\Users\Family\Desktop\GABA Project\GABA Structures\New Ligands With Hydrogens\Similar To Valium\Mcule 6HUP Entire ECD Diazepam RENUMBERING TEST'  # first define the subdirectory
pathway_tree = os.walk(pathway)

os.chdir(pathway)
for subdir, dirs, files_in_dirs in pathway_tree:
    #print(f"dirs! {dirs}")
    pass

    for file_names in files_in_dirs:
        try:
            if "Partial Pocket" in file_names and ".pdb" in file_names:


                os.chdir(subdir) # changes to the specific sub directory using the great filter
                with open(file_names, "r") as input:

                    for input_file_line in input:
                        # captures each line in the file as an item in an array

                        array_of_words_in_line = input_file_line.split() # further splits the line in the file as its own array with each item # being a string 
                       

                        three_letter_code = array_of_words_in_line[3] # ie, UNK

                        if three_letter_code == "UNL" or three_letter_code == "UNK" or three_letter_code == "LIG":
                            prepend_line(file_names, input_file_line)

        except IndexError:
            pass

        except NameError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a completely new list of lines, and then write those lines to an output file:

```py
i = 0
new_text = []
with open(filename, "r") as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if line.split()[3] in {"UNL", "UNK", "LIG"}:
            new_text.insert(i, line) # reinsert at start of list
            i += 1
        else:
            new_text.append(line) # append to the end of the list

new_text = "".join(new_text)
with open(filename, "w") as fo:
    fo.write(new_text)
```

Comment: The lines already have `\n` at the end. Using `"\n".join()` will double-space the file. You should strip the newline off `line` whan putting it into `new_text`.

Comment: Is this compatible with os.walk() ? I'm using the os library because my data files are scattered throughout several different subdirectories, and I'm not working with just one file.

Answer (score 0):

This type of text-based data processing is basically what Unix command line tools were made for. Here is a oneliner to do it with [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
$ (sed -n /UNL/p data.txt; sed /UNL/d data.txt) > processed_data.txt
```

Explanation: the first `sed` invocation prints all lines containing `UNL`. The second one deletes all lines containing `UNL`. The combined output is redirected to `processed_data.txt`.

Comment: This is a shell command. The `$` sign indicates your shell prompt. You could run it from Python using [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). Alternatively, you could use another shell command, `find`, to perform the directory walking.

Comment: while this  looks interesting, I know very little about shell commands and Unix. I don't want to have a new output file I just want to modify a series existing files located throughout numerous subdirectories.

Comment: Whenever you feel ready, I highly advise you to go down the rabbit hole of `bash`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, and related utilities like `cat`, `cut`, `sort`, and `uniq`. A good starting point is [this answer on Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2436).